# Run android animation on onCreate method

Tags: android

I want to run my android animation soon after the application starts.
I am using frame animation with an animation list in thunder.xml.
My code is given below.

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animlist);    
img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.thunder);  
AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
frameAnimation.start();
```

But this is running but not showing the animation.
If i create a button and set this as the onClick event of that button, then its working correctly.
But i want to run my android animation soon after the application starts. 
Please help me ..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try moving your code in onStart() method. I guess your animation is running but till the activity is started your animation animation is finished.

Comment: I moved my code to onStart() method, still the same problem.Can any1 help. Is there any other way to implement this??

Comment: @yshak You have accepted this answer, and comment that "still the same problem". Does it solve the question or not?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, It may helps you -

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    animation = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageAnimation);
    animation.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animation);      
}

public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus) 
{
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = 
        (AnimationDrawable) animation.getBackground();
    if(hasFocus) {
        frameAnimation.start();
    } else {
        frameAnimation.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onWindowFocusChanged()` is the correct method to call out `start()` on frame animation.